# Behavior of screen over ssh + cygwin / screen detachment

Tags: ssh, cygwin, gnu-screen

When I use screen, it works fine except up to the point where I need to re-attach. My suspicion is that the sort of "shelled" environment I am using is not letting screen fully detach although I am unsure of whether that is the case.

My current environment is this: ssh -> cygwin bash shell -> screen

Everything works fine but when I try to attach with screen -r (id), the command doesn't do anything, I don't get any output and when checking with screen -ls the screen session is still listed as detached. I researched this but can only come up with other people who either get a dead screen session or some error. I don't get either, the command runs and gives no output leaving the screen detached. I have a feeling this is something to do with screen not detaching fully because of the layered shells but have no idea how to fix it.

Any suggestions?